# Looking for movie - Underground laser tank

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm trying to remember a movie I saw many years ago.  I think the movie was made in the late 60's or early 70's.

One of the main gadgets was a kind of tank that burrowed underground with a laser cannon sticking out a tube in front.

I seem to remember that the movie had a lot of cold war USA vs USSR politics at the beginning.  The plot twist was that the Americans believed the Soviets had a burrowing laser tank.  However they were shocked to find out that actually the other tank was Chinese.

Even as a kid, I remembered that the burrowing laser tanks were painted plywood boxes on golf-carts.  Also they made the weirdest noise when the laser was on.  It sounded like a cross between an organ and car horn.

Can anyone link me to suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it perhaps "Battle Beneath the Earth"?
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0061387/

Comment: Yes! that was the movie!  gosh it was terrible!  Thank you very much!